# 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a contact form and after submitting I am getting a Net::SMTPAuthenticationError `535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted`

It's pointing to the create action in the contacts controller `ContactMailer.new_contact(@contact).deliver`

I have restarted the server. I tried https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha.

I am in development.

Contacts controller:

```
 def new
      @contact = Contact.new
    end

    def create
      @contact = Contact.new(params[:message])
      if @contact.valid?
        ContactMailer.new_contact(@contact).deliver
        flash[:notice] = "Message sent! Thank you for contacting us."
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        render :action => 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Development.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    port:                 587,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    user_name:            'username@gmail.com',
    password:             'password',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true  }

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "localhost:3000" }
```

Comment: You have to use a valid gmail account, and use its credentials to authenticate to Gmail servers and send the email.

Comment: I am using a valid gmail account. It's my personal account that I use daily.

Comment: If you have `2-step authentication` setup on you gmail account then you **cannot** use the regular password. In that case you would have to generate an *application specific password* and use that in your  `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat `2-step authentication` is disabled.

Comment: I don't use the line `enable_starttls_auto: true` in my config with Gmail.

Comment: Thank you @MrYoshiji that was the fix indeed.

Comment: My gmail account worked in local development environment but when I transferred it to production server it failed, I logged into that account in a browser then I visited this url and enabled the new device (production server) then problem was solved https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

Answer (score 36, accepted):

First, You need to use a valid Gmail account with your credentials.

Second, In my app I don't use TLS auto, try without this line:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'YOUR_USERNAME@gmail.com',
  password:             'YOUR_PASSWORD',
  authentication:       'plain'
  # enable_starttls_auto: true
  # ^ ^ remove this option ^ ^
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: (See answer below for details) now you need to enable "less secure apps" on your Google Account

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: Actually, I use `enable_starttls_auto: true` in smtp_settings all the time and it works perfectly. It is a valid option and is also specified in [Action Mailer Configuration for Gmail in Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail). May be the problem was related to server certificate: [check :enable_starttls_auto option here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.0/guides/source/action_mailer_basics.md#action-mailer-configuration)

Comment: I was having the same problem -- I am also using `enable_stattls_auto: true ` and it is now working.  In the end it started by restarting rails server -- my settings are exactly the same as when I was started having the issue.

Comment: For me, this worked: **SMTP server: gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com, Port: 465, SSL: True**

Comment: I had to disable `2 factor authentication`, enable `less secure apps` (https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps), and then use my actual password and not the app generated one.

Comment: Another way is to set up App password.  Enabling **less secure apps** is not a correct approach.  You will still be able to send emails keeping your 2-factor authentication on. Please refer https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833.  If it is a specific custom application, not one that is listed in the dropdown to generate the app password, just type a name and click **GENERATE**.  I was able to set it up this way.

Comment: enable "less secure apps" fixed it for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 109):

I had the same problem. Now its working fine after doing below changes.

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

You should change the "Access for less secure apps" to Enabled (it was enabled, I changed to disabled and than back to enabled). After a while I could send email.

Comment: Yes its compulsory to turn on less secure app  from google account.

Comment: @RavindraBhalothia but isnt it bad practise to allow acces for less secure apps? Google wouldnt just like that implement this feature

Comment: As of May 30, 2022, [this option is no longer available](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255)

Comment: @Dahn, any other workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: @PrithvipalSingh I sadly do not know of any

Comment: We need to use an app password instead of a standard password. We need to enable 2-factor authentication before setting the app password. Here is the link: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Answer (score 34):

Time flies, the way I do without enabling `less secured app` is making a password for specific app

Step one: enable 2FA

- https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome

Step two: create an app-specific password

- https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

After this, put the *sixteen digits password* to the settings and reload the app, enjoy!

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    ...
    password: 'HERE', # <---
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
```

Comment: By 2FA it worked !

Comment: Indeed! To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.

Answer (score 16):

Google stopped allowing apps logging in to Gmail using real password

> After 30 May 2022 you can't login with username and password alone to
> Gmail. Less secure app access is not available anymore unless you have
> Google Workspace or Google Cloud Identity.

Source: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

You need to make a password for specific app

Step one: enable 2FA

- https://myaccount.google.com/signinoptions/two-step-verification/enroll-welcome

Step two: create an app-specific password

- https://myaccount.google.com/apppasswords

[image]

After this, use that 16 digit

Comment: This fixes the problem that less secure applications are not supported anymore! Thank you

Comment: This is correct as of 2022. Since allow less secure app access is disabled by google. You should follow this or go with OAuth method.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:**

> ***Notice***: This setting **is not available** for accounts **with 2-Step Verification enabled**, which mean you have to **disable 2 factor
> authentication.**

[image]

If you disable the 2-Step Verification:

- Open your Gmail account in browser
- Navigate to [Less secure app access](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)
- Make **Allow less secure apps** => **On**

[image]

Comment: this is the answer, I was scrolling down to post this and found your answer. Good work brother. Jazakkum Allah Khair

Comment: my pleasure bro :)

Answer (score 5):

"From May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password." https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

you need only create a password for you applications, and use it

Solution

1. Go to your Google Account (click on your avatar -> Manage your Google Account(above list of yout all account))
2. Find Security Menu (left side menu)
3. Enable 2-Step Verification
4. After that you will see "App Password" option in Security page. (If not search it in Google Account Search box.
5. Select Mail from the "Select App" dropdown
6. Select the device from "Device" dropdown and click the "Generate" button.
   Copy password and use it in your application where required.

here was similar issue: [Nodemailer with Gmail | There was an error: Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70606793/nodemailer-with-gmail-there-was-an-error-error-invalid-login-535-5-7-8-user)

Answer (score 4):

**Word of caution**

After 30 May 2022 you can't login with username and password alone to Gmail. Less secure app access is not available anymore unless you have Google Workspace or Google Cloud Identity.

Source: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: This post was a life saver!

Answer (score 4):

Do simple these steps

1. After sign in your google account click on below your photo icon

   ```
    "Manage your Google Account"
   ```
2. then click on "security" tab.
3. Find "How you sign in to Google"
4. Then google need to on "2-Step Verification"
5. After do it by giving your account password. Go to bottom of page and find

   "App passwords"
6. Click on "select app" in my case i select other and giving name "website".
7. The password will be generated, this will be your password for
   configuration of smtp rather than your actual account password.

   ```
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port                 => 587,
      :user_name            => 'your-email@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'google generated password',
      :authentication       => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
    }
   ```

This will sure work!

Answer (score 3):

The less Secure App feature is now gone, but you can use the APP PASSWORD Feature instead. It worked for me.

To do this,

1. go to your google account and then turn On the 2-step Verification.
2. Then, on the "Search Google Account bar," type "App Passwords" and then click "App Passwords."
3. Then, it will require you to log in again.
4. Select the app and device you want to generate the app password for. In this case, select "Mail" and then "Other" to Customize a device name.
5. Lastly, click GENERATE. Use this as your SMTP-AUTH Account Password instead of your regular Gmail password.

The best solution for anyone who has encountered the error "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted" on Web Based Management while setting the SMTP on Printing Machines.

Answer (score 2):

Goto `config/initializers/setup_mail.rb` Check whether the configuration there matches the configuration written in the `development.rb` file.It should look like the following in both files:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     :address =>"smtp.gmabirdvision17@gmail.comil.com",
     :port => 587,
     :domain => "gmail.com",
     :user_name => "PPPPPPPP@gmail.com",
     :password => "********",
     :authentication => 'plain',
     :enable_starttls_auto => true,
     :openssl_verify_mode => 'none' 
     }
```

This will most certainly solve your problem.

Comment: You just published your gmail credentials. Update your password ASAP.

Comment: @Axxiss you saved my life

Comment: @Supertracer But your password is still available at this link http://stackoverflow.com/posts/32455654/revisions , so u must change it

Answer (score 1):

If you still cannot solve the problem after you turn on the `less secure apps`.
The other possible reason which might cause this error is you are not using gmail account.

```
-    : user_name  =>  'example@company.com' ,  # It can not be used since it is not a gmail address 
+    : user_name  =>  'example@gmail.com' ,  # since it's a gmail address
```

Refer to [here](https://qiita.com/Yinaura/items/6886682a607951a71bac).

Also, bear in mind that it might take some times to enable the `less secure apps`. I have to do it several times (before it works, every time I access the link it will shows that it is `off`) and wait for a while until it really work.

Answer (score 1):

If you've tried all the answers above, and none of them worked, here is the actual problem. In my case it worked

1. Gmail doesn't like passwords that are more than 14 symbols. It may work when you login with browser, but from an pplication, it doesn't.
2. So you have 14 symbol password and you want to change it. Your changes are successful and you can login with the changed password from browser, but guess what, the changes are valid only after few hours. **So try to run your applications  a few hours later with the changed password, and it will work.**
3. If you want to test that this solution will work for you, just try to fill your personal gmail login and password to see if it works on other accounts.

Comment: Worked for me after changing the password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case removing 2 factor authentication solves my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I did everything from visiting http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha to setting up 2-fa and creating an application password. The only thing that worked was logging into http://mail.google.com and sending an email from the server itself.