# SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8 https://support.google

Tags: python, email, yagmail

I have a problem with this following code i juste want to send an email to my own mail using Yagmail.

My code :

```
yagmail.register('abscenseuser', 'admin')
yagmail.SMTP('absenceuser').send('samuel.louismarie@gmail.com', 'absence', 'Vous n avez pas declarer vos absences')
```

Comment: Did you read the given webpage?

Comment: Your question contains part of answer. If you'll take a look on the given web page, that you will see the reason. You should allow 3rd party application access.

Comment: What do you mean about the given webpage ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137012/535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted