# How to solve code: 'EAUTH', response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted.responseCode: 535, command: 'AUTH PLAIN'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gmail, nodemailer

I have a contact me form in my website and I'm trying to send an email using gmail service and it's working flawlessly in my local dev environment, but I'm having this issue:

> {code: 'EAUTH', response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Lear…mail/?p=BadCredentials e19sm4851511qty.16 - gsmtp', responseCode: 535, command: 'AUTH PLAIN'}

I googled a lot and looked in the docs but all I found was to make the "Less secure app access" option in Google accounts turned on, and I did that, I tried turning it off and on and I made sure it was working in my local machine, but unfortunately it's not working in when I send the request to my API in Vercel endpoint.

my React code

```
const sendContactForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    Axios.post(
      `${
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? process.env.REACT_APP_API_LOCAL_URL
          : process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
      }/contact`,
      {
        theName,
        email,
        subject,
        msg
      }
    )
      .then(({ data }) => {
        setSendStatus(data.sendStatus)
        setSendStatusMsg(data.sendStatusMsg)
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err))
  }
```

And my NodeJS code is:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer')
const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport')

module.exports = (req, res) => {
  const { theName, email, msg, subject } = req.body
  // const { MAILER_EMAIL, MAILER_PASS } = process.env

  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
    smtpTransport({
      service: 'gmail',
      port: 465,
      // secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL,
        pass: process.env.MAILER_PASS
      }
    })
  )

  const mailOptions = {
    from: email,
    to: process.env.MAILER_EMAIL,
    subject: subject,

    html: `<p>here is simply HTML code</p>`
  }

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      res.send({
        sendStatusMsg: 'Sorry! something went wrong!',
        errResponse: err,
        sendStatus: 0
      })
    } else {
      res.send({
        sendStatusMsg: 'Thanks for contacting us',
        infoResponse: info.response,
        sendStatus: 1
      })
    }
  })
}
```

And thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23137012/535-5-7-8-username-and-password-not-accepted) with the same issue. It has other recommendations besides enabling less secure apps, you can review it and see if it helps

Also, some recomend to use [XOAuth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/imap/xoauth2-protocol) instead to authenticate